# Why doesn't array.map change anything?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to format the data i got from YouTube Data API v3 but i'm unable to change anything of it.

```
const videoIds = youtubeResponse.items.map(item => item.id);
VideoRepo.getById(videoIds, (err, videos) => {
    /* 
    videos is an array of objects that contain youtube videos from YT API and MongoDB(mongoose)
    */
    console.log(videos.map((v) => {
        v.time = moment(v.time).fromNow();
        v.duration = moment('1900-01-01 00:00:00').seconds(v.duration).format('HH:mm:ss');
        return v;
    }));
});
```

VideoRepo class:

```
  static getById(id, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(id)) {
      // Multiple ids were specified
      async.waterfall([
        (next) => {
          // Get existing videos' data
          Video.find({ _id: { $in: id } }).select('-__v').sort({ createdAt: 1 }).exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            next(null, data);
          });
        },
        (existingData, next) => {
          if (existingData.length === 0) {
            // All videos are new, skip to the next step
            return next(null, [], id);
          }
          // Remove existing data from ID array
          const obj = existingData.map(el => el._id);
          next(null, existingData, id.filter(el => !obj.includes(el)));
        },
        (existingData, newIDs, next) => {
          if (newIDs.length === 0) {
            return next(null, existingData);
          }
          // Get new videos' data from YT API
          youtube.videos.list({ id: newIDs.join(','), part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics' }, (err, videoResp) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            // Final data
            const data = id;

            // New videos' data
            const newData = videoResp.data.items.map(item => this.fixVideoData(item));
            // Add new videos to the DB
            Video.insertMany(newData, (err) => {
              if (err) return next(err);
              // Merge new data with existing data
              const merged = existingData.concat(newData);
              // Fix order
              for (let i = 0; i < merged.length; i += 1) {
                const d = merged[i];
                data[data.indexOf(d._id)] = d;
              }
              // Success!
              next(null, data);
            });
          });
        },
      ], (err, data) => callback(err, data));
    }
  }

  static fixVideoData(videoData) {
    const data = {
      _id: videoData.id,
      channelId: videoData.snippet.channelId,
      title: videoData.snippet.title,
      description: videoData.snippet.description,
      slug: slugify(videoData.snippet.title, { lower: true }),
      views: videoData.statistics.viewCount,
      duration: moment.duration(videoData.contentDetails.duration).asSeconds(),
      tags: videoData.snippet.tags,
      thumbnail: null,
      preThumbnail: null,
      time: videoData.snippet.publishedAt,
    };

    const possibleThumbs = ['maxres', 'standard', 'high', 'medium', 'default'];
    for (let j = 0; j < possibleThumbs.length; j += 1) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(videoData.snippet.thumbnails, possibleThumbs[j])) {
        data.thumbnail = videoData.snippet.thumbnails[possibleThumbs[j]].url;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (videoData.snippet.thumbnails.medium) {
      data.preThumbnail = videoData.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
    } else if (videoData.snippet.thumbnails.high) {
      data.preThumbnail = videoData.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
    } else {
      data.preThumbnail = data.thumbnail;
    }

    return data;
  }
```

This is what `videos` array contains:

```
// videoData: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource
{
    _id: videoData.id,
    channelId: videoData.snippet.channelId,
    title: videoData.snippet.title,
    description: videoData.snippet.description,
    views: videoData.statistics.viewCount,
    duration: moment.duration(videoData.contentDetails.duration).asSeconds(),
    tags: videoData.snippet.tags,
    thumbnail: null,
    preThumbnail: null,
    time: videoData.snippet.publishedAt,
};
```

Expected results:

```
[...{ [..other keys] duration: "00:05:43", time: "3 days ago" }]
```

Actual output (nothing is changed, exactly the same array as `videos`):

```
[...{ [..other keys] duration: 343, time: 2018-12-26T13:37:32.000Z }]
```

Why is it not working and how can i fix it?

Comment: The usage seems correct to me. Is there any chance we can get some additional infos? are you sure you're looking at the correct log? The only reason I can think of is that those property are readonly (getters), though it should throw an exception.

Comment: Can you add an example of the _actual_ data rather than how it's constructed.

Comment: Updated the post with getById function.

Comment: @user123 No, he was asking about what **data** (JSON) looks like, not getById function

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev I don't know how i can post the data, i updated the post with the whole class that creates and returns the data. I'm using YouTube Data API v3 but if you mean the data in mongodb, here's a screenshot of a video: http://prntscr.com/m10mbo

Comment: @user123 Are you sure that you've posted the code as it is on your machine?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Yes, except the `class VideoRepository {` part, stackoverflow didn't let me post that much code.

Comment: `const data = id;` what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Try printing `Object.isFrozen(videos[0]);`.  Your code looks good, the only thing I can think is that the objects are being returned to you pre-frozen with `Object.freeze()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a new object where you override only those 2 specific keys,

```
video.map(v => ({ 
    ...v, 
    duration: moment('1900-01-01 00:00:00').seconds(v.duration).format('HH:mm:ss'),
    time: moment(v.time).fromNow()
}))
```

Comment: Yes he can, but why should he? His code is OK at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently `Model.find()` returns mongoose documents instead of javascript objects and i should have used [Query.lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean).

```
Video.find({ _id: { $in: id } }).lean().select('-__v').sort({ createdAt: 1 })
        .exec()
```

Comment: Maybe `v` was some immutable object i.e. proxy that ignores changes.